# How do you divide a matrix by a vector along the other axis in numpy?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an n x n matrix, *p*, that I want to divide by a n x 1 vector, *q*. When using p/q (or equivalently np.divide(p,q)), it treats each row as a row vector and divides each one elementwise with *q*. I want a similar thing but columns instead of rows (i.e. each row of *p* should be divided by the corresponding element of *q*, a la `p[i,:]/q[i]`).

I've tried using a loop which is fairly easy, but the size of n is too large for this to be feasible going forward.

Otherwise, I've only really found np.divide() and that doesn't have an `axis` keyword.

Comment: Is `q` *really* n x 1, or is it actually just 1-dimensional? Because if it was really n x 1, then `p/q` would have worked.

Comment: (And if it's actually just 1-dimensional, then making it n x 1 solves the problem.)

Comment: The question was solved down below, but I'm not sure I understand your comment and I'd like to. What is the difference between n x 1 and 1D? I meant q is a row or column vector (when I take its transpose with numpy it just gives me the same thing, so I'm not sure which)

Comment: If transposing doesn't change it, then it's 1D. It's neither a row vector nor a column vector. Those are 2D concepts. Your vector is truly 1-dimensional.

Comment: NumPy isn't a matrix library. It doesn't force vectors to carry around an extra length-1 dimension so they can be matrices. Arrays can have 1 dimension, or 3, or even 0. It's more like a tensor library than a matrix library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into the [broadcasting section](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) of the documentation.

Here is a demonstration:

```py
import numpy as np

N = 3

p = np.arange(N * N).reshape(N, N) + 1
q = np.arange(N) + 1

q1N = q[None, :]  # q.reshape(1, N)
qN1 = q[:, None]  # q.reshape(N, 1)
```

Then you have:

```py
>>> p
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]

>>> q
[1 2 3]

>>> p / q
[[1.  1.  1. ]
 [4.  2.5 2. ]
 [7.  4.  3. ]]

>>> p / q1N
[[1.  1.  1. ]
 [4.  2.5 2. ]
 [7.  4.  3. ]]

>>> p / qN1
[[1.         2.         3.        ]
 [2.         2.5        3.        ]
 [2.33333333 2.66666667 3.        ]]
```